# CSS: Div alignment, not aligning like I want it to

Tags: html, css, alignment, wrapper, vertical-alignment

div not aligning

[image: 1]

The picture above is the issue, I want the div to align with the right side div. I was able to do it for my 3rd div and it looks like this. [how I want alignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJ4eA.png)

Here is the sandbox to see: https://jsfiddle.net/drtripod/5uyre361/#&togetherjs=dwgrRImtgT

```
.wrapper {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 80px);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.form-wrapper.sign-up {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 80px);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.login-left {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-left: 150px;
  background-color: white;
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}

.sign-up {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-left: 150px;
  background-color: white;
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;

.login-right {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
}
```

I tried to add padding or change the width and height which did not end up working because when I resized the window it just lost its alignment

Answer (score 0):

you just need to change "flex-direction: row;" property in the class ".login-form-footer" in your sandbox.